# Error while trying to install selenium in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu

I have installed python in my ubuntu machine which is of version 18.0 by using command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

It has two versions of python installed

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-OptiPlex-960:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.15rc1

ubuntu@ubuntu-OptiPlex-960:~$ python
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

ubuntu@ubuntu-OptiPlex-960:~$ python3 -V
Python 3.6.5
```

I am installing selenium using command:

```
$ sudo pip install selenium
```

It is giving error as :

```
The directory '/home/ubuntu/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not 
owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the 
permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may 
want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/ubuntu/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned 
by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the 
permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may 
want sudo's -H flag.

Collecting selenium
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement selenium (from 
versions: )
No matching distribution found for selenium
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you installed the pip with sudo ?